# Exporting specific pattern of string using split method in a most efficient way

Tags: java, string, methods, pattern-matching

I want to export pattern of bit stream in a String varilable. Assume our bit stream is something like bitStream="111000001010000100001111". I am looking for a Java code to save this bit stream in a specific array (assume bitArray) in a way that all continous "0"s or "1"s be saved in one array element. In this example output would be somethins like this:

```
bitArray[0]="111"
bitArray[1]="00000"
bitArray[2]="1"
bitArray[3]="0"
bitArray[4]="1"
bitArray[5]="0000"
bitArray[6]="1"
bitArray[7]="0000"
bitArray[8]="1111"
```

I want to using bitArray to calculate the number of bit which is stored in each continous stream. For example in this case the final output would be, "3,5,1,1,1,4,1,4,4". I figure it out that probably "split" method would solve this for me. But I dont know what splitting pattern would do that for me, if i Using `bitStream.split("1+")` it would split on contious "1" pattern, if i using `bitStream.split("0+")` it will do that base on continous"0" but how it could be based on both?

Mathew suggested this solution and it works:

```
var wholeString = "111000001010000100001111";
wholeString = wholeString.replace('10', '1,0');
wholeString = wholeString.replace('01', '0,1');
stringSplit = wholeString.split(',');
```

My question is "**Is this solution the most efficient one?"**

Comment: Does your result have to be in order? For example, could `bitArray[1]` contain `111` and `bitArray[0]` contain `00000`?

Comment: Yes, in same order as appearance.

Comment: regarding the question about efficiency, I think that it's impossibile to do it with a complexity less than O(n), because you have to evaluate at least all the string in some way

Comment: See my answer for the results of a small performance test I did on 4 of the listed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple regular expression. It matches 1s and 0s and will return each in the order they occur in the stream. How you store or manipulate the results is up to you. Here is some example code.

```
String testString = "111000001010000100001111";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("1+|0+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);

while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.print(matcher.group().length());
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

This will result in the following output:

```
3 5 1 1 1 4 1 4 4
```

One option for storing the results is to put them in an `ArrayList<Integer>`

Since the OP wanted most efficient, I did some tests to see how long each answer takes to iterate over a large stream 10000 times and came up with the following results. In each test the times were different but the order of fastest to slowest remained the same. I know tick performance testing has it's issues like not accounting for system load but I just wanted a quick test.

```
My answer completed in 1145 ms
Alessio's answer completed in 1202 ms
Matthew Lee Keith's answer completed in 2002 ms
Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer completed in 2556 ms
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing any occurrence of "01" and "10" with "0,1" and "1,0" respectively. Then once you've injected the commas, split the string using the comma as the delimiting character.

```
String wholeString = "111000001010000100001111"

wholeString = wholeString.replace("10", "1,0");
wholeString = wholeString.replace("01", "0,1");

String stringSplit[] = wholeString.split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn for translating my JS into Java. I knew logically how to get it done, just not familiar with the exact nuances of Java vs JS. Tried to use a language I knew that was at least similar.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you a code, but I'll guide you to a possible solution:

Construct an [`ArrayList<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), iterate on the array of bits, as long as you have 1's, increment a counter and as soon as you have 0, add the counter to the `ArrayList`. After this procedure, you'll have an `ArrayList` that contain numbers, etc: [1,2,2,3,4] - Representing a serieses of 1's and 0's.
This will represent the sequences of 1's and 0's. Then you construct an *array* of the size of the `ArrayList`, and fill it accordingly.

The time complexity is O(n) because you need to iterate on the array only once.

Comment: And probably I should also do that in a situation that the bitStream start with "0". But is it the most efficient answer? Because in my case "n" and also the number of calling this method is really large.

Comment: No. You do this in any way. You just need to have a flag indicating what's the first number in the array of bits.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for any String and patterns, not only 1s and 0s. Iterate char by char, and if the current char is equal to the previous one, append the last char to the last element of the List, otherwise create a new element in the list.

```
public List<String> getArray(String input){

    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(input==null || input.length==0) return output;
    int count = 0;
    char [] inputA = input.toCharArray();
    output.add(inputA[0]+"");
    for(int i = 1; i <inputA.length;i++){
        if(inputA[i]==inputA[i-1]){
            String current = output.get(count)+inputA[i];
            output.remove(count);
            output.add(current);
        }
        else{
            output.add(inputA[i]+"");
            count++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String[] a = s.replaceAll("(.)(?!\\1)", "$1,").split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement @Maroun Maroun solution.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String bitStream ="0111000001010000100001111";
    int length = bitStream.length();
    char base = bitStream.charAt(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count = -1;
    char currChar = ' ';
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        currChar = bitStream.charAt(i);
        if (currChar == base){
            count++;
        }else {
            base = currChar;
            counts.add(count+1);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    counts.add(count+1);
    System.out.println("Time taken :" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start ) +"ms");
    System.out.println(counts.toString());
}
```

I believe it is more effecient way, as he said it is O(n) , you are iterating only once. Since the goal to get the count only not to store it as array. i woul recommen this. Even if we use Regular Expression ( internal it would have to iterate any way )

Result out put is

```
Time taken :0ms
[1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Try wrapping that solution in a loop with >= 10000 iterations and a much longer stream string. This will give a better scaled timing result than just 0. Be sure to only include the needed items inside the outer performance loop, timing and setup can be done outside that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=1)(?=0)|(?<=0)(?=1)");
```

See in action here: http://rubular.com/r/qyyfHNAo0T